# How can I link a custom post type from the admin submenu in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wp-admin

> I created a custom post type and I hide it
>
> using `register_post_type()`
>
> and a menu page using
>
> `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()`

the link for the custom post type is `page=edit.php?post_type=survey`

and for the menu page is `admin.php?page=my_survey`

I hide the `custom post type` because I don't want to show it, I just want to have one menu but with a link to the sub menu page that goes to the `custom post type`

> the problem is that all the links in the menu have the prefix
>   `admin.php?page=` when I add the link in the
>
> `menu_slug => 'edit.php?post_type=survey'`
>
> it adds `admin.php?page=edit.php?post_type=survey`

is it anyway that I can remove that prefix from just one sub menu ?

I'm working on a OOP 
this is how I add the submenu

```
  public function setSubPages()
  { 
    $this->subpages = [
      [
        'parent_slug'  => 'survey',
        'page_title'  => 'Survey Plugin',
        'menu_title'  => 'Survey',
        'capability'  => 'manage_options',
        'menu_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=survey',
        'callback'    =>   [$this->callbacks, 'adminDashboard'],
      ];
  }
```

and my custom post type

```
  public function activate()
  {
    $labels =  [
      'name' => 'survey',
      'singular_name' => 'survey',

    ];

    $args = [
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt',
      'supports' => false,
      'exclude_from_search' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => false,
      'show_in_menu'       => false
    ];

    register_post_type( 'survey', $args );

  }
```

if I wasn't clear enough please let me know
thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solve the problem, for those are having the same problem
hope that helps

custom post type

```
      public function activate()
      {
        $labels =  [
          'name' => 'Email List',
          'singular_name' => 'Email List',

        ];

        $args = [
          'labels' => $labels,
          'public' => false,
          'has_archive' => false,
          'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt',
          'supports' => false,
          'exclude_from_search' => true,
          'publicly_queryable' => false,
          'show_in_menu'       => 'survey_plugin'  // <----- admin page menu_slug
        ];

        register_post_type( 'surveyemail', $args );

      }
```

admin survey page

```
public function setPages()
  { 
    $this->pages = [
      [
        'page_title'  => 'Survey Plugin',
        'menu_title'  => 'survey',
        'capability'  => 'manage_options',
        'menu_slug'   => 'survey_plugin', // same as show_in_menu custom post type
        'callback'    =>   [$this->callbacks, 'adminDashboard'],
        'icon_url'    => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'position'    => 25
      ]
    ];

  }

  public function setSubPages()
  { 
    $this->subpages = [
      [
        'parent_slug'  => 'survey_plugin', // match menu_slug $this->page
        'page_title'  => 'Welcome',
        'menu_title'  => 'Welcome page',
        'capability'  => 'manage_options',
        'menu_slug'   => 'Welcome',
        'callback'    =>   [$this->callbacks, 'adminDashboard'],
      ],
      [
        'parent_slug'  => 'survey_plugin',// match menu_slug $this->page
        'page_title'  => 'feedback',
        'menu_title'  => 'feedback',
        'capability'  => 'manage_options',
        'menu_slug'   => 'feedback',
        'callback'    =>   [$this->callbacks, 'adminDashboard'],
      ]


    ];
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no sense in having `public` set to `true` if you unset each of its effects in the parameters afterwards (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Second thing: You can not use the menu slug in this way because it is defined as follows:

> **$menu_slug**
>
> (string) (Required) The slug name to refer to this menu by. Should be
>   unique for this menu and only include lowercase alphanumeric, dashes,
>   and underscores characters to be compatible with sanitize_key().

However there is a way to create custom submenu URLs. Please check the following thread on SO WordPress for further information: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83768/add-menu-and-submenu-in-admin-with-a-url-instead-of-slug?answertab=votes#tab-top

Be careful what you do in WP-Admin though, if you want to have a post type editable in WP-Admin it is usually the best way to have it editable by parameters.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I will check the link to see what can I do